# Is there a keyboard shortcut in Xcode 4.2 for inline search?

Tags: xcode

I'm looking for something like <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> in emacs or <kbd>CTRL/CMD</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> in eclipse that will search the file I'm currently in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>; <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> to search ALL files in your project.

Comment: cool i guess if i hit escape after the match is highlighted it works the same.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 4, main editor, press <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>6</kbd>, then type something and you will see. If you wanna search files like that - use <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>5</kbd>.

Comment: Oh nice thanks! That's pretty awesome. I'm definitely liking that CTRL-5 a lot.